# Creating TabBar programmatically only for one ViewController not in AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create a tabBar in my app but only in a detailView not in the AppDelegate. I am searching how to do this in google but everything what I have figured out is in `AppDelegate.m`

I am trying to do something like this. This shows me a Tab bar with two buttons(without names) but I want to go from one FirstViewController with tabBar, to one of the two items SecondViewController or ThirdViewController with a navigationBar with one backItemButton for get back to the FirstViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupTabBar];
}
- (void) setupTabBar {

    tabBars = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *localViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];


    YPProfileViewController *profile = [[YPProfileViewController alloc] init];
    YPProfileViewController *profile2 = [[YPProfileViewController alloc] init];

    [localViewControllersArray addObject:profile];
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:profile2];


    tabBars.tabBarItem = profile2;
    tabBars.viewControllers = localViewControllersArray;
    tabBars.view.autoresizingMask==(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);


    [self.view addSubview:tabBars.view];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at least this works for me.

```
UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc1.title = @"FIRST";
vc1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc2.title = @"SECOND";
vc2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBar.viewControllers = @[vc1,vc2];
tabBar.selectedIndex   = 1;
tabBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 220, 320);

[tabBar willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:tabBar.view];
[self addChildViewController:tabBar];
[tabBar didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```